# How to get ride of first an empty array nested inside an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm trying to compare two arrays, I'm receiving some values from Text components and pushing it into a new array, and while I want to compare them it's returns false even if the value of both arrays match, and this is because the first item of an array returns an empty array with values.

and this is how it looks like:

Array_1

```
Array_1 = [
  Array [],
  "Hi",
  ",",
  "how",
  "are",
  "you",
  "?",
]
```

Array_2

```
Array_2 = [
  "Hi",
  ",",
  "how",
  "are",
  "you",
  "?",
]
```

An this is where the value goes into a new array which is Array_1

```
    //Get selected value
  const handleSelected = (e) => {
    setReceivedItems(e);
  };

  //Update selected data at first render
  useEffect(() => {
    setNewItems((newItem) => [...newItem, receivedItems]);
  }, [receivedItems]);
```

Do you think this is happen due to useState [] initial value ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: From your question it is not quite clear how your script relates to the two arrays listed above it. Do you want the comparison-function applied to two arrays return "true"?

Comment: Yes just true or false
but it's returning false every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to compare the elements of two arrays one by one, ignoring any sub-arrays that might exist, then the following should do the job:

```js
const Array_1 = [[],"Hi",",","how","are","you","?"],
 Array_2 = ["Hi",",","how",["this is being ignored too!",""],"are","you","?"],
 Array_3 = [[],"Hi",",","How","are","you","?"];

function arrComp(...args){ 
 const [aa,bb]= args.map(ar=>ar.filter(e=>!Array.isArray(e)));
 return aa.every((a,i)=>a===bb[i])
}
console.log(arrComp(Array_1,Array_2)); // true
console.log(arrComp(Array_1,Array_3)); // false
```